# Adding IHS server details under ant script

Tags: ant, websphere, ear

I have an ant script to deploy the EAR file to my Websphere application server. This server is under clustered environment and has a cell with its respective nodes.

I also have an IHS server above this WAS instance which my application uses.

Requesting to kindly guide as to how the ant script can be used to deploy the EAR file on cluster by providing the required IHS server details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the section in $WASHOME/bin/configureWebserverDefinition.jacl that iterates through the existing web modules and maps them to the newly created webserver.

In Jython, from the manual:

```
AdminApp.edit('myapp', ['-MapModulesToServers',
 [['.*', '.*', '-WebSphere:cell=mycell,node=mynode,server=server1']]])
```

But you'd need to substitue the full name for your webserver.